# Sorting is not working for longtext field django mysql

Tags: mysql, django

I have a field called "Question_Number" with data type LONGTEXT. The values can be integer, alphanumeric and Roman numbers. How can I sort this in a proper way? I have already tried so many sorting methods, but not working.

The query which I have tried:

```
questions = questions.extra(select={'ques_numbernew': "CAST(ques_number as SIGNED)"}).extra(order_by = ['ques_numbernew']).order_by('ques_number')
```

Using regular expression:

```
questions = Questions.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM database_questions WHERE test_id=%s ORDER BY ques_number REGEXP "^\d*[^\da-z&\.\' \-\"\!\@\#\$\%\^\*\(\)\;\:\\,\?\/\~\`\|\_\-]" ASC, ques_number + 0, ques_number;',[test_id])
```

I got the right sorting idea. Now I'm getting cheerful output. If anyone need sorting for mixed varchar field can make use of this sorting.

Query:

```
questions = Questions.objects.filter(test_id=test_id).extra({'ques_num': "ques_number + 0"}).extra(order_by = ['ques_num','ques_number','subquestion'])
```

Comment: Share what have you tried with enough details.

Comment: thank you for edit of question. But still not enough. Show some samples

Comment: I gave the answer. Now i'm getting right output@middlestump